# Continuous errors occurring while trying to run a file importing pygame on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame, traceback

I have been struggling for the past few hours on what I should do, and finally decided to resort to asking on StackOverflow.

PROBLEM: I keep getting terminal traceback calls but I have no idea what I should do about them. I will admit, it is probably me being stupid and not knowing what is happening, but it was my first time on VSCode and importing stuff. When I googled at first, I couldn’t get any answers.

CODE (I have a second file with dvd-image.png):

```
import pygame, time

pygame.init()
width, height = 800, 600
dvdLogoSpeed = [1, 1]
backgroundColor = 0, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

dvdLogo = pygame.image.load("dvd-image.png")
dvdLogoRect = dvdLogo.get_rect()

while True:
    screen.fill(backgroundColor)

    screen.blit(dvdLogo, dvdLogoRect)
    dvdLogoRect = dvdLogoRect.move(dvdLogoSpeed)

    if dvdLogoRect.left < 0 or dvdLogoRect.right > width:
        dvdLogoSpeed[0] = -dvdLogoSpeed[0]
    if dvdLogoRect.top < 0 or dvdLogoRect.bottom > height:
        dvdLogoSpeed[1] = -dvdLogoSpeed[1]

    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(10 / 1000)
```

TRACEBACK CALLS:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/untitled101/pygame.py", line 1, in 
> import pygame
> File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/untitled101/pygame.py", line 3, in 
> pygame.init()
> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)

EXTRA INFORMATION:

- Device: MacBook Air
- Chip: M1
- VSCode Download: Universal
- Coder: Knows nothing good about tracebacks

Comment: Basically, a traceback is an error that includes where it happened. Here, it happened in the file `pygame.py`, line three, where you do `pygame.init()` - I don't know enough about pygame to help explain the error, though.

Comment: Your traceback says you have a file `/Users/cadmarlegend/Desktop/untitled101/pygame.py` that is trying to import `pygame`. But because you have called your program `pygame.py`, that is masking the real `pygame` module. Call your program something else.

Comment: And maybe that will let you begin to see that tracebacks contain valuable information, if you take the trouble to read them.

Comment: ok, so it was the naming? thank you very much for the help! I knew that it was happening on the line, but I didn’t know what exactly I could do to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`pygame`** is a Python package and you have your own project named "pygame".

Pylance will recognize your project as the pygame package.

You can change your projcet name to solve it.